# How can I integrate silverlight 3 with asp.net

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I created an asp.net application. How can I integrate a silverlight tag to my asp.net project. When i googled I got some of the examples for 2.0 . Where can I get an example solution for silverlight 3.0?

Note : when I searched for the same in google, i got a solution to add a `system.web.silverlight.dll` that is present in my %win%/Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Server\system.web.silverlight.dll

for **3.0** %win%/Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Server\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll is there no system.web.silverlight.dll .

What i need to do, to integrate the silverlight into my asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add those assemblies to your asp.net website as they are for development of the Silverlight project.

All you need is:

1. Silverlight 3 plug-in the user's machine
2. a XAP file which is the compiled Silverlight 3 binary
3. Latest Silverlight.js
4. Some markup in your html or aspx page like example below (ClientBin/BIA1.XAP is the binary used)

It's much easier to just install the Silverlight Tools for VS2008 and let set it up for you by adding a New Silverlight project to your solution, it will ask you if you want to integrated to your existing asp.net website with a test html file created. [Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displaylang=en)

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">           
        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/BIA1.xap"/>
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
        </a>
    </object>
```